# My camera won't stop in walk navigation mode

Tags: camera, navigation

In walk navigation mode, I press E to move the camera up, but the camera keeps moving up without stopping.

When I press E, I want the camera to move a little like when I press WASD.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you have deactivated KeyMapItem `Stop Move Up` in Preferences > Keymap > 3D View > View3D Walk Modal?

Comment: Oh, You are right. I changed the move up key and the move down key. But I didn't know there is Stop Move Up key. Now it is working properly. Thank you